# Anime about teens with powers on a flying ship

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime about teens with powers on a flying ship. The main character is a girl with secret fire powers. They try to stop someone from resetting the world.

The ship goes around getting people with these abilities.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or places or the name of the ship?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're thinking of ***[Norn9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norn9#Anime)***...?

According to the Wikipedia page, it initially aired in 2016, and was based on a PlayStation Portable game published two years earlier.

> *Norn9* (NORN9 ノルン＋ノネット, *Norn9 Norun+Nonetto*) is an otome game for PlayStation Portable. It was developed by Otomate and published by Idea Factory. The game was originally going to be launched on May 23, 2013, but its release was delayed one week. A PlayStation Vita port, entitled *Norn9: Var Commons*, was released on December 11, 2014. A fandisk titled *Norn9: Last Era* has been announced and was released on April 2, 2015. On March 2, 2014, it was announced that an anime adaptation was in the works. **The anime ran from January 7 to March 31, 2016.**

The same page also gives a brief description of one of the main characters, Koharu, a girl with the power to manipulate fire.

> **Koharu is a cheerful, innocent, sweet and kind girl with short pink hair and the ability to manipulate fire.** Because of her ability's tremendous destructive power, people mocked and called her a monster, leading to her to forget her name. Her current name "Koharu" was then given to her by Shiro, who told her about the ship Norn9. Because she is the newest on the ship, she has the least knowledge and very observant of everything around her. As the series progresses, she develops a relationship with Kakeru.

[The TV Tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VisualNovel/Norn9) offers a pretty good overview of the plot, which apparently involves various teenagers with powers travelling aboard a flying ship.

> A young boy named Sorata Suzuhara is on a field trip when he suddenly finds himself whisked back in time to the Taisho Era. There, he meets a girl who displays the power of fire to keep him warm.
>
> **The two are soon picked up by a strange globe-shaped ship**... and find themselves attacked by two of the other passengers. Once the misunderstanding is cleared up, Sorata learns that **the girl and the other passengers are known as "espers - People who have power over things like plants, fire, water, etc.**
>
> The espers are making their way to The World, a mysterious entity that guides the nations of the world to peace. But there are people who don't want them to reach their destination. Worse yet, there might be a traitor among them.

A number of flying ships are visible in this trailer, along with the main characters.